# How to wrap two widgets content into single DIV element in Blogger?

Tags: blogger

I want to design a blogger template. But the problem is I don't understand how to wrap two widgets into one DIV element. Here is my HTML structure for sidebar-

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="top-logo">
        <img src=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-content">
        <ul class="list1>
            <li>Item1</li>
            <li>Item2</li>
            <li>Item3</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="list2>
            <li>Item1</li>
            <li>Item2</li>
            <li>Item3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I have created a section called sidebar and the widgets like this

```
<b:section id='sidebar' class='sidebar' showaddelement='yes'>
    <!-- sidebar top logo-->
    <b:widget id='Image1' locked='true' title='Logo' type='Image'>
        some code
    </b:widget>

    <!-- sidebar link1-->
    <b:widget id='HTML1' locked='true' title='Sidebar Link1 type='HTML'>
        some code
    </b:widget>

    <!-- sidebar link2-->
    <b:widget id='Label1' locked='false' title='List all label' type='Label'>
        some code
    </b:widget>
</b:section>
```

now my question is how to wrap the **link1** and **Label1** widgets into **sidebar-content** div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [A section](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/46888) can only contain widgets. To insert extra code within a
>   section, split the section into two or more new sections.

You can do something like this

```xml
<div class="sidebar">

    <b:section id='top-logo' class='top-logo' showaddelement='yes'>
        <!-- sidebar top logo-->
        <b:widget id='Image1' locked='true' title='Logo' type='Image'>
            some code
        </b:widget>
    </b:section>

    <b:section id='sidebar-content' class='sidebar-content' showaddelement='yes'>
        <!-- sidebar link1-->
        <b:widget id='HTML1' locked='true' title='Sidebar Link1 type='HTML'>
            some code
        </b:widget>

        <!-- sidebar link2-->
        <b:widget id='Label1' locked='false' title='List all label' type='Label'>
            some code
        </b:widget>
    </b:section>

</div>
```